# Is narcissism an eponym?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

The story of Narcissus from Ovid's *Metamorphoses* was the name giver for the term narcissism, which means "unhealthy and/or excessive self-love".

The definition of an eponym on Wikipedia is:
An eponym is a person, place, or thing for whom or for which something is named, or believed to be named.

So, my question is: Is narcissism an eponym?

Comment: By the definition you quote, Narcissus would be the eponym.  But "A name or noun formed after a person" is also a definition for eponym: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eponym

Comment: Actually, using the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym) definition you provided, narcissism is *not* an eponym, but *Narcissus* is. However, other sources like the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eponym) an eponym is **also** *a name or noun formed after a person*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems **narcissism** can rightly be said to be an example of **eponym,** as per its etymology.

> **[narcissism](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=narcissism)** ([Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=narcissism))
>
> 1905, from German Narzissismus, coined 1899 (in "Die sexuellen Perversitäten"), by German psychiatrist Paul Näcke (1851-1913), on a
>   comparison suggested 1898 by Havelock Ellis, from Greek Narkissos,
>   name of a beautiful youth in mythology (Ovid, "Metamorphoses,"
>   iii.370) who fell in love with his own reflection in a spring and was
>   turned to the flower narcissus (q.v.). Coleridge used the word in a
>   letter from 1822.